# In angular, how to add element to the view and db, then delete it directly after without knowing the id?

Tags: angular, database, service, subject

Here is my problem.
I have a list of folder like that :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Folder } from '../models/folder.model';
import { FoldersService } from '../services/folders.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-folders-list',
  templateUrl: './folders-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folders-list.component.scss']
})
export class FoldersListComponent implements OnInit {

  folders: Folder[];
  folderSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private foldersService: FoldersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.folderSubscription = this.foldersService.folderSubject.subscribe(
      (folders: Folder[]) => {
        this.folders = folders;
      }
    );
    this.foldersService.emitFolderSubject();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.folderSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const title = form.value['title'];
    const newFolder = new Folder(title);
    this.foldersService.createNewFolder(newFolder);
  }

}
```

All data are managed by the FolderService below. Only him interact with the database. When I post, get or delete element from the database, the service does it.
My problem is the following one:
When I create an element, the database herself manages the id, I mean the database choose an id by autoincrement. But to directly delete it after, I need this id ! I only found two solutions that seem weird to me:

- Reupdate the view by doing an other "getFolders" request. But if the list is huge, I would have to make a huge get request after each post request...
- Choose an ID in the app, but it would change my whole app logic...
  Any ideas ?

  ```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { Folder } from '../models/folder.model';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FoldersService {

      private folders: Folder[] = [];
      folderSubject = new Subject<Folder[]>();

      private url:string = environment.BACKEND_HTTPS_SERVER;
      private endpoint:string = "/folders";

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getFolders();
      }

      emitFolderSubject() {
        this.folderSubject.next(this.folders.slice());
      }

      getFolders() {
        this.http
          .get<any>(this.url+this.endpoint)
          .subscribe(
            (response) => {
              this.folders = response;
              this.emitFolderSubject()
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log('Error : ' + error);
            }
          )
      }

      createNewFolder(newFolder: Folder) {
        //this.folders.push(newFolder);
        this.http
          .post(this.url+this.endpoint, {
            "title": newFolder.title
          })
          .subscribe(
            (_) => {
              console.log("Successfully added.");
              this.getFolders();
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log("Error : ", error);
            }
          )
      }

      deleteFolder(id: number) {
        const elementPos = this.folders.map(function(o) { return o.folderId;}).indexOf(id);
        this.folders.splice(elementPos,1);
        this.http
          .delete(this.url+this.endpoint+"/"+id)
          .subscribe(
            (_) => {
              console.log("Successfully deleted.");
              this.emitFolderSubject();
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log("Error : ", error);
            }
          )
      }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your backend is configured, the `http.post` often returns the new saved object with the id as set by the backend server. So you can access it in your subscribe, something like this:

```
.subscribe(
          folder => {
            console.log("Successfully added folder: " + folder.id);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("Error : ", error);
          }
        )
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier to help if we knew what is your database and your backend.

Getting the Id back after adding an item isn't hard, but if you ***realllllyy*** can't, I used to work on a DB where we had to use a GUID (which isn't the primary key) to identify our items in the db. It's just sad to add a field in your table just to delete an item.

The GUID can be generated in the Angular side, so it's easy to call for a DELETE or whatever you want.